# Struggling with loop and and opening pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, loops

I am not very experienced with jQuery, I would like to have this pop-up open on the div it is in (so something with $(this) I assume, just can't get it working :(), when I click `<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Bekijk trekker</a>`. What's happening now is that it opens every pop-up for every item in the loop. Here's my jQuery and HTML.

```
<div class="container">

    <h1> Trekkers </h1>

    <section id="filter">
        Filter
    </section>

    <section id="tractoren">

        <?php
            $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'tractoren', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1 
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>

            <div class="tractor">

                <figure>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('tr_thumb'); ?>
                </figure>

                <div id="content">

                    <h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                    <span> Bouwjaar: <?php the_field('tractoren_bouwjaar'); ?> </span>
                    <span> Uren: <?php the_field('tractoren_uren'); ?> </span>

        <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Bekijk trekker</a>

        <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
            <div class="popup-inner">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
                <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>

          $(function() {

              $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
                  var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
                  $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
                  e.preventDefault();
              });

              $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
                  var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
                  $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
                  e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
        </script>

                </div>

                <span class="price">
                    <?php if( get_field('tractoren_prijs') ): ?>
                        <?php the_field('tractoren_prijs'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if( !get_field('tractoren_prijs') ): ?>
                        <?php echo 'Prijs onbekend' ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </span>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </section>

</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to make use of the classes that you already have like `.btn` and `.popup-close`.

You can use **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** method for opening the popup:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).next('.popup').fadeIn();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

and **[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** for close:

```
$('.popup-close').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Demonstrative snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next('.popup').fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('.popup-close').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <h1> Trekkers </h1>

  <section id="filter">
    Filter
  </section>

  <section id="tractoren">


    <div class="tractor">

      <figure>
        some image
      </figure>

      <div id="content">

        <h3>
          some title </h3>
        <span> Bouwjaar: <?php the_field('tractoren_bouwjaar'); ?> </span>
        <span> Uren: <?php the_field('tractoren_uren'); ?> </span>

        <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Bekijk trekker</a>

        <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
          <div class="popup-inner">
            <h2>
              some popup title
            </h2>
            <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" class='popup-close' href="#">Close</a></p>
            <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <span class="price">
                    <?php if( get_field('tractoren_prijs') ): ?>
                        <?php the_field('tractoren_prijs'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if( !get_field('tractoren_prijs') ): ?>
                        <?php echo 'Prijs onbekend' ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </span>

    </div>
 <div class="tractor">

      <figure>
        some image
      </figure>

      <div id="content">

        <h3>
          some title </h3>
        <span> Bouwjaar: <?php the_field('tractoren_bouwjaar'); ?> </span>
        <span> Uren: <?php the_field('tractoren_uren'); ?> </span>

        <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Bekijk trekker</a>

        <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
          <div class="popup-inner">
            <h2>
              some popup title
            </h2>
            <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" class='popup-close' href="#">Close</a></p>
            <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <span class="price">
                    <?php if( get_field('tractoren_prijs') ): ?>
                        <?php the_field('tractoren_prijs'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if( !get_field('tractoren_prijs') ): ?>
                        <?php echo 'Prijs onbekend' ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </span>

    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Frisidan,  awesome. Happy to help. I've also updated the answer a bit after observing that you had the jQuery code inside the loop. Don't do that. Put it outside the loop. You only need it once.